# Buttons labelled with the number of times they have been clicked

Tags: beginner, html, gui, elm

I am new to functional programming and I decided to learn it thru Elm instead of haskell. I wrote a practice code where there are 2 buttons and their names correspond to the number of times they are clicked. The following is my implementation:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

main = Html.beginnerProgram {model=model, view=view, update=update}

-- model
type alias Model = 
   { a : Int
   , b : Int
   , total : Int}

model : Model
model = Model 0 0 0

 -- view
type Msg = Add Foo
type Foo = A | B

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
   div [] 
     [ button [onClick (Add A)] [text (toString model.a)]
     , button [onClick (Add B)] [text (toString model.b)]
     , div [] [ text (toString model.total)]
     ]


 -- update
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
   case msg of
     Add foo ->
       case foo of
         A ->
           let
             a = model.a + 1
             total = a + model.b
           in
             {model | a = a, total = total}
         B ->
           let
             b = model.b + 1
             total = b + model.a
           in
             {model | b = b, total = total}
```

I feel like that the above code is a dumb implementation of what I wanted to accomplish. Can somebody suggest a better implementation?

Comment: I recommend you configure your editor to *format-on-save* using [elm-format](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format)

Comment: Thank you. I just learned how to do that. BTW, any idea why elm-format uses 4-spaces indentation? It's a bit too much for me. I think 2 spaces are enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few things I'd recommend changing:

1. There's no need to store the sum of `a` and `b`. You can always compute it in the view with `a + b`. This simplifies the `update` function a lot.
2. You can match `Foo A` and `Foo B` in `update` instead of a nested case.
3. Optionally, you can destructure `model` into `{a, b}` in `view`. I don't have any opinion on this. Either way is fine.

Here's the final elm-format'd code:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)


main =
    Html.beginnerProgram { model = model, view = view, update = update }


type alias Model =
    { a : Int
    , b : Int
    }


model : Model
model =
    Model 0 0


type Msg
    = Add Foo


type Foo
    = A
    | B


view : Model -> Html Msg
view { a, b } =
    div []
        [ button [ onClick (Add A) ] [ text (toString a) ]
        , button [ onClick (Add B) ] [ text (toString b) ]
        , div [] [ text (toString (a + b)) ]
        ]


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Add A ->
            { model | a = model.a + 1 }

        Add B ->
            { model | b = model.b + 1 }
```

Live: https://ellie-app.com/c7GLFrXx3a1/0

Comment: Wow, this greatly simplified the code. Many thanks for pointing out number (2). Your answer is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's one more change I'd personally make: use `<|` to reduce parentheses: `text (toString a)` -> `text <| toString a` and similar for the two lines below.

Comment: Ooh, that's nice. I'll practice on using that operator to reduce my use of parentheses.